# Is KuTools from extendoffice.com safe?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I wanted to install kutools for excel from extend office using this [link](https://www.extendoffice.com/product/kutools-for-excel.html). After downloading the file, I checked on virustotal and it says it is malicious[image]

Is it legit?
Am I downloading from the wrong website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KuTools from extendoffice.com is a well-known product and is not new on the
market. It is however commercial in nature (no free version).

It happened to me several times when testing a product on VirusTotal
that one product (and only one) detected it as dangerous.
However, if the detection was not by one of the main antivirus
products, I ignore this minority opinion.

In any case, the latest Windows Defender is an excellent antivirus with
excellent detection capabilities. If it finds nothing when you install it,
then you are most likely safe.

Be sure to download it only from
[extendoffice.com](https://www.extendoffice.com/).